# Using CSS Grid on a Django Template

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, css-grid

I have a div container in my HTML which displays a list of 10 parsed headlines from The Toronto Star. I want to be able to display them in a **repeating** grid that looks like this:

[image: Here's the example image ( I can't add images since I dont have 10 reputation yet )]

Here's the django template that I have :

```
<div id="container">
<div class="containers">
    {% for n, i in toronto %}
    <center><img src="{{i}}"></center>
    <h3>{{n}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

To clarify, I am asking for someone who is **experienced with CSS Grids** and django to help me with the appropiate css code similar to the picture i referenced above. The css grid needs to be repeating as well as the django template contains 10 indexes in its list

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm afraid broad questions are considered as offtopic here. Try to make your question more specific, point to concrete problem you've faced _implementing_ your "repeating grid". I see no grid in your code at all.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try

```html
<div id="container">
{% for n, i in toronto %}
<div class="containers">
    <center><img src="{{i}}"></center>
    <h3>{{n}}</h3>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

The class has to be parsed too

Comment: I was asking about what the css would look like. I dont have much experience in CSS Grid, So i was asking how id code a repeating grid similar to the picture i referenced in the post